# C#, EF Core 3, concurrency, how to achieve parallel processing with write/read operations to SQL database correctly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, .net-core, parallel-processing

I am in the middle of an data import project, I have an old DB from which I extract data, do a lot of processing to make it "fit" into the new DB and then I write it to the new DB.

I am trying to speed this process up as there are millions of records I need to process and a single threaded process is just too slow. I currently do it in this fashion:

```
SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(8);

var tasks = policyVersionDictionary.Select(async pv =>
{

    await _sem.WaitAsync();

    await using (var dbThread = new ApplicationDbContext(connectionString))
    {

        try
        {
            dbThread.Database.SetCommandTimeout(240);

            var listOfPolicyVersions = pv.Value;

            var horseService = new HorseTransferServiceMultithreading(dbThread);

            await horseService.ProcessHorse(listOfPolicyVersions);

        }
        finally
        {
            _sem.Release();

            // Probably an overkill as we're inside 'using'
            dbThread.Database.CloseConnection();
            dbThread.Dispose();

        }
    }

}).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`_sem` is controlling the number of threads, I spawn a new dbContext for each item in the policyVersionDictionary, I spawn a new `HorseTransferServiceMultithreading` too as I want it to be separate for each operation (thread).

the `horseService.ProcessHorse(listOfPolicyVersions);` method is a wrapper method for the whole lot of processing that needs to be done for each item, including reading/writing to the database multiple times.

This already works quicker than a single threaded way of doing it, but I am not sure whether this is the correct way of doing concurrency/parallel processing. I have read a ton of posts about calamities that happen when you write parallel code that reads/writes from the database, deadlocks, errors and all sorts, but I don't know enough about this method to be able to tell whether I'm doing it right or am I making a massive mistake.

Is there a better way? Should this be completely avoided? If so, how should import projects be tackled in order to be somewhat quick? Currently, it runs for around 48h (not just this piece of code) which is pretty long and I would ideally like to make it much quicker.

Comment: Looks like you're using EF. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, sorry, will edit the question to add this in.

Comment: Can you also add info about your DB

Comment: standard SQL on SQL Server 14.0.1000

Comment: In my experience, using entity framework for this kind of bulk data transfer is one of the slowest ways of proceeding. Are you transferring to an "in-service" database, or do you have the luxury of doing this off-line?

Comment: I can do it offline as the "Live" import will happen over the weekend when the new system eventually goes live. I will be able to run it on a beefy server just to make sure it does it bit quicker than 2 days. I will basically take a copy of the old DB since the client won't work on it over the weekend.

Comment: @spender EF is being used as the data structure is very different in both databases and doing it just in SQL would be a nightmare due to the amount of data processing that needs to be done to "pigeonhole" all the records.

Comment: So, in my opinion, the bottleneck here is unlikely to be solved by throwing more threads at the problem. If it were me, I would probably only have a single writer to the DB. Most likely, the best speed up you can acheive is by disabling indexes in the database for the duration of the writing, then rebuilding them once your data is inserted. The permanent updating of indexes can really make inserts chug. Unless you're absolutely positive that "more threads" will give you more speed, my opinion is that you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: This is probably worth looking into: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Comment: @spender I tested the speed on few thousand records and multithreading does speed it up, I'm only hoping it does not slow down after few hours. Indexes is something that has been mentioned to me already so I will try and do this. I also would like to only have single writer to the DB however, I have to use the methods written for the core system to "simulate" adding the records organically - which is another problem, as they do have Save/Read commands in them, and I can't just rewrite it all. Regarding my code posted above - is there any obvious issues with it or is it a common practice?

Comment: Is multithreading really speeding up the *writes*? Or is it that your writer thread(s) are occupied with non-writing activites for part of their time-slice? I can't really comment on the correctness of your code because we're only looking at a small top-level slice of your solution... I think you need to work hard to identify what's really costing the time here, but IMO, EF is probably your biggest burden in this scenario. Make sure you've checked out the documentation thoroughly to ensure that your DbContext isn't taking on work that isn't necessary.

Comment: @spender Each thread does the same exact thing - takes the data, processes is heavily and creates a record in the new DB. Each has it's own dbContext so they don't conflict. I don't know if "writes" are faster themselves, the overall time is quicker, but probably as you say, it's because non-writing activities are a big part of the task. As long as it doesn't clog up the connections to the SQL - it must be faster by design as it's running 8 processes at the same time rather then processing each record one by one

Comment: I would recommend 1) Using ADO.NET or Dapper rather than EF for the bulk reads/writes; and 2) Adopting TPL Dataflow to define the transformation pipeline.